# psycopg2 in Azure Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, psycopg2

I have a script to connect to a localhost PostgreSQL server at 127.0.0.1 on port 5432.  It runs without error in a local Jupyter notebook.  But when I upload and run it in an Azure Jupyter notebook it throws an error:
"OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Here: https://github.com/chasbecker/PostgreSQL/blob/master/psycopg2-test.ipynb

Again, it runs without error on a local Jupyter notebook.  I'm stumped.  Any ideas?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is very clear. On your local machine you have a postgres database running in the correct host:port, in Azure you do not.